# How to increase the height, width of the table layout?

Tags: android, android-layout

I wanted to know how to increase the size of the table layout??I have placed the textviews and edittext  in table rows that appear on the left side of the screen. I wanted to design similar to this [image]

Comment: Post your layout here

Answer (score 0):

You can use       `android:minHeight="60px"` or assign the width/height to `fill_parent`.